# Bar button Item to open multiple URLs?

Tags: iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I recently saw the code down below. Is it possible to link a bar button item to multiple URLs? i.e. by tapping the button, I can then choose which website I wish to go to at runtime? Or can I only link a bar button to one URL?

```
override func  viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
googleButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapGoogle", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)}
```

and

```
@IBAction func didTapGoogle(sender: AnyObject) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com")!)}
```

Comment: Try to store url in a variable on bar button click, then create a common function in which you need to pass url.

Comment: Would you have an example?

Comment: Are you trying to link multiple URL's to single button or there are multiple button?

Comment: Ideally, just 1 button.

Comment: How will you choose URL at runtime?

Comment: You have to add sidebar menu on tap of barbutton with option like google, yahoo etc. if there is only a one bar button then how would you recognize which URL has to be open.

Comment: I was wondering whether you could choose from a popover or something similar on button tap, same style as a popover for sharing via e-mail, twitter etc. Otherwise, I'll just have to stick with one button for one URL. @Hasya - exactly my question - if statements maybe?

Comment: I am gonna give the sidebar menu a shot, guys. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as sidebar menu.

This library keeps your sidebar menu over viewcontroller and navigation bar.

https://github.com/balram3429/BTSimpleSideMenu

It is in objective c, but you can use it by bridging. there are other side bar menus are also available in swift, just make sure it has to be open over view controller and navigation bar.

Import this 2 in bridging file.

//#import "BTSimpleSideMenuClass.h"

//#import "BTSimpleMenuItemClass.h"

Make object

```
var objBTSimpleSideMenuClass = BTSimpleSideMenuClass()
```

Import delegate

```
class YourClassName: UIViewController, BTSimpleSideMenuDelegate {

}
```

From ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear call this method and pass array with name, image etc

```
func setupOptionMenu(noOfItems : NSMutableArray)
{
    objBTSimpleSideMenuClass.delegate = self

    let ary : NSMutableArray = []

    for var i = 0; i < noOfItems.count; i++
    {
        let item = BTSimpleMenuItemClass.init(title: noOfItems[i] as! String, image: nil) { (success, item) -> Void in


            self.methodOptionMenuTap1()

            //self.methodOptionMenuTap2()

            //self.methodOptionMenuTap3() 

        }

        ary.addObject(item)
    }

    let swiftArray = ary as NSArray

    objBTSimpleSideMenuClass =  BTSimpleSideMenuClass.init(item: swiftArray as [AnyObject], addToViewController: self)



}
```

Hope this will help you a lot.

All the best.